# What is the difference between posting to feed and uploading to photo album with Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the fundamental difference between uploading photos to an album or posting directly to the users wall? I want to provide the user with the best experience possible on my application, I also want to use an approach that also benefits my application in terms of social promotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's the same as when done manually, isn't it? Posting to wall gives you one post with photo in it, and posting to album gives you link to album with some thumbnails on your wall.

Comment: I wasn't sure, I just wondered what the "standard" approach among developers is for posting images. I would have thought that most developers would prefer to post to feed instead of uploading to albums.